# How can I convert many images into a movie?

Tags: command-line, convert

How can I convert many images into a movie?

I have about 12000 images, and I want to create a movie based on the timestamps of the images. The timestamp is also the filename. I tried using `convert` but it crashes my PC when I try to do it. What is a good command-line way to solve this problem?

Comment: you want to make a slide show? you need a movie editor/creater not convert

Comment: When you say 'timestamp' can you give an example of the exact image filenames?

Comment: I have used Openshot to do it. You can install it from the repositories. (I think it is easy to use Openshot in order to create a video clip from a series of pictures, but it is a GUI program, and you are asking for a command line way.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `ffmpeg`, from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/249101/how-can-i-combine-30-000-images-into-a-timelapse-movie/510295#510295):

> ```
> cd /path/to/images
> ffmpeg -f image2  -r 1/5 -pattern_type glob -i './*.png' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
> ```

The other option is `mencoder`. I didn't test it, but you can find some instructions [here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/249101/how-can-i-combine-30-000-images-into-a-timelapse-movie/249141#249141).

And it looks like [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/412294/365303) works fine for a huge number of images:

> ```
> ls -1v | grep JPG > files.txt
> mencoder -nosound -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=21600000 -o windowsill_flowers_7.avi -mf type=jpeg:fps=24 mf://@files.txt -vf scale=1920:1080
> ```

Comment: I tried this, but it fails with: Unknown encoder 'libx264'

I also tried:`#apt-get install libav-tools libavcodec-extra libx264-dev` updating, upgrading, and rebooting. unknown encoders is still coming up.

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause could be, it worked fine without installing anything in my Ubuntu 16.04, however you can try installing `libx264-148` package ... it might help.